# Joining lines into a single line in TextEdit

Tags: text, textedit

In a text document, how do I join several lines into a single line? I want each paragraph to be on a single line, but keep the lines between the paragraphs.

Here is an example. I want to convert this text

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
>     adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
>     adipiscing vitae, felis.
>
> Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
>     libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
>     vehicula augue eu neque.

to this text

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
>     adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, 
>     adipiscing vitae, felis.
>
> Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu 
>     libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec 
>     vehicula augue eu neque.

I know how to do it in `vim` or `fmt`, but can I do it in TextEdit and in the builtin text boxes? I don't want to manually have to do `^D<space>` at the end of each line.

Comment: I have to ask: why don't you just make such editing changes in vim and then do the rest of the editing (e.g., formatting) in Text Edit?

Comment: I will simply go with a C++ application fast. LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the each paragraph of the document. Paste it in the browser address bar. Copy it again from the address bar and paste it in your document.
The outcome for each paste should be that part of the document on single line.
Will only be practical of course if you have limited number of paragraphs.

Answer (score 7):

If your paragraphs are separated by a blank line, you can do this with a two-part Find and Replace in TextEdit.

1. Open the **Find and Replace** dialog (⌥⌘F).
2. In the **Find** field, insert the newline character by typing <kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>return</kbd>.
3. In the **Replace** field, insert a space, then click **All**. This replaces all newlines with a space, so you'll have one long line of all your text.
4. Change the **Find** field to *two* spaces.
5. In the **Replace** field, enter two newline characters (<kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>return</kbd> twice).
6. Click **All** to move paragraphs to a new line.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. It *almost* does what I want, which is to turn paragraphs separated by empty lines into single lines.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify this in your question a bit, perhaps post a sample and the result you expect. You want each paragraph to be on a single line, but keep the lines in between the paragraphs?

Comment: Exactly. I've updated my question as you suggest.

Comment: Updated it with the process to work the way you're looking for.

Comment: This seems to work for RTF but not plain text. If the document you are editing is in plain text, the lines are not merged.

Answer (score 2):

I find this works best in three steps, particularly if there's some character or combination of characters not used in your document. Let's assume for a moment that `•%•` doesn't happen to come up in your document. If it does, pick a different arbitrary short string.

- Use the **Find and Replace** dialog to replace all double newlines (<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>) with your arbitrary text string; replace all.
- **Find and Replace** all newlines (<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>) with a space (<kbd>space</kbd>).
- **Find and Replace** all instances of your arbitrary text string with a double newline.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a service like this:

[image]

With AppleScript you'd have to use the clipboard:

```
try
    set old to the clipboard as record
end try
try
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down
    delay 0.1
    do shell script "export LC_CTYPE=UTF-8; pbpaste | fmt -w 99999 | pbcopy"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
    delay 0.1
end try
try
    set the clipboard to old
end try
```

I have also written a script like TextMate's filter through command (run shell script.scpt at http://lri.me/applescript.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just run this workflow. This worked for me:

**Ask for Finder items**

**Open Finder Items** (using TextEdit)

**Wait for Finder Items**

**Get Contents of Text Edit Document**

**Remove Empty Paragraphs**

**Get Paragraphs of Text**

**Combine Text String** (Select Insert Delimiter Between Combined strings, then put one space in that field)

**New Text File**

That should work. Let me know if it does.